# Telerik ReportViewer Paging not enabled

Tags: telerik, telerik-reporting

I have Telerik version 8.1.14.804 installed and my project is built in VS2013 with framework 4.0, but when the reportviewer is rendered the paging arrows are not enabled. I don't see any properties for enabling these. Is there another feature or code that needs to be written?

Comment: Can you attach a screenshot? and make sure that the report contains data that should be displayed on more than one page?

Comment: Which report viewer?  Windows, HTML5, etc?